# Azure app using custom domain with SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https, azure

Could someone explain the steps that one must do to show an Azure application (example.cloudapp.net) in a custom domain (service.example.com), when we want to use a secured connection? So the users browse to https://service.example.com, see it as a certified, trusted domain, and can safely access the application.

Right now, I think that

1) we need a domain (and subdomain) with a static IP from a service provider
2) we need a certificate from a CA for our domain

But I'm not quite sure how the connection between our domain and cloudapp.net should be made. I have found many examples and blog posts, but they tell either how to install a certificate to Azure application or how to show the application in custom domain (without the certificate).

This sounds like a basic requirement, so I'd expect a rather simple solution to exist.

Thanks!

Comment: You do not need to get any static IP for this. The domain name would be binded by Azure hosted application using CNAME record.

Comment: But isn't it so that web servers require to have static IP for the certificate? If we didn't need certificate, I could understand how to proceed but we need to tie up the certificate to our custom domain, which is what I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this blog entry
[Custom Domain Names in Windows Azure](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/custom-domain-names-in-windows-azure)

Basically you need to buy domain name and add some CNAME record in DNS table. The part remaining would be to buy appropriate SSL certificate for your site.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. We have looked that. The blog post doesn't take into account how to use certificate with custom domain. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: As i understand when you buy a certificate you map it to a domain. Once you buy a certificate for your domain, the certificate needs to be imported into your Azure deployment using Management portal. The certificate also needs to be registered with you VS Azure project under Certificate section of webrole properties. See this link for more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff795779.aspx

Comment: I do not believe that Azure currently supports using a certificate with a custom domain (see request for feature: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/3007732-make-it-possible-to-use-ssl-on-blob-storage-using%29).  In the meantime, you can use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stop-gap for custom domains: http://www.bradygaster.com/running-ssl-with-windows-azure-web-sites

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe that Azure currently supports using a certificate with a custom domain ([see request for feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/3007732-make-it-possible-to-use-ssl-on-blob-storage-using%29)).  In the meantime, you can use [CORS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535601.aspx).